# Convert functional components into class component React

Tags: react-native

I've just started learning react native for about a month and only focus on the class but my push notifications (expo docs) I find are written with react hooks, I have some access issues on the side class but I don't know anything about hooks .... please help me switch my class. Thanks everyone.I tried switching to class but got a lot of errors
https://docs.expo.io/push-notifications/overview/

Answer (score 1):

For exp push notification (class type component) , please use the following :

```
import React, {Component}  from 'react';
//import { Notifications } from 'expo';
import * as Notifications from 'expo-notifications';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import {
    Alert,
    Vibration, Platform,
    Image,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  AsyncStorage,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

Notifications.setNotificationHandler({
  handleNotification: async () => ({
    shouldShowAlert: true,
    shouldPlaySound: false,
    shouldSetBadge: false,
  }),
});


export default class xxxxxx extends Component {

 state = {
    expoPushToken: '',
    notification: {},
  };

  registerForPushNotificationsAsync = async () => {
   
      let token;
    
      if (Constants.isDevice) {
    const { status: existingStatus } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
    let finalStatus = existingStatus;
    if (existingStatus !== 'granted') {
      const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.NOTIFICATIONS);
      finalStatus = status;
    }
    if (finalStatus !== 'granted') {
      alert('Failed to get push token for push notification!');
      return;
    }
    token = (await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()).data;

      
//this.setState({
//      xbuttonstate: false
//    })    

    
     this.setState({expoPushToken:token})

// alert(this.state.expoPushToken);
// unremark the above if you want to see the expoPushToken

  } else {
    alert('Must use physical device for Push Notifications');
  }
    
    
    
    
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('default', {
      name: 'default',
      importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
      vibrationPattern: [0, 250, 250, 250],
      lightColor: '#FF231F7C',
    });
  }
    
    
    
  };

/// Add other codes you want (e.g. render /view )

}
```